# How to transform the following dataframe using R

Tags: r

I am using R for generating statistical reports for past 6 months. I got a requirement as mentioned below:

Input DataFrame:

```
 FY_Qtr       region     Lic_type    revenue
 2009 Q1         AP       NCV       126.67
 2010 Q1         NA       NCV       395.80
 2011 Q1         LA       NCV       469.10
 2012 Q1         EMEA     MR        173.85
 2013 Q1         JAPAN    MR        140.24
```

Expected Data:

```
  FY_Qtr       AP.NCV   NA.NCV   LA.NCV   EMEA.MR JAPAN.MR
 2009 Q1       126.67   -           -       -       -
 2010 Q1        -       395.80      -       -       -
 2011 Q1        -       -           469.10  -       -
 2012 Q1        -       -           -       173.85  -
 2013 Q1        -       -           -       -       140.24
```

Can any one help me on this to get the Expected Data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is exactly the type of task that the 'reshape2' package was built for.

**Setup**: Let's load in the sample data.

```
data <- read.table(text="
     FY_Qtr       region     Lic_type    revenue
     '2009 Q1'         'AP'       NCV       126.67
     '2010 Q1'         'NA'       NCV       395.80
     '2011 Q1'         'LA'       NCV       469.10
     '2012 Q1'         'EMEA'     MR        173.85
     '2013 Q1'         'JAPAN'    MR        140.24
    ", header=TRUE)
```

**Cast the data**: Essentially what you have right now is considered "melted" data.  You have ID columns with a separate row for every set of variable combinations and an assigned value.  This means you can skip the usual 'reshape2' step of melting the data first and skip straight to casting, like so:

```
library(reshape2)

dcast(data, FY_Qtr ~ region + Lic_type, value.var='revenue')

#    FY_Qtr AP_NCV EMEA_MR JAPAN_MR LA_NCV NA_NCV
# 1 2009 Q1 126.67      NA       NA     NA     NA
# 2 2010 Q1     NA      NA       NA     NA  395.8
# 3 2011 Q1     NA      NA       NA  469.1     NA
# 4 2012 Q1     NA  173.85       NA     NA     NA
# 5 2013 Q1     NA      NA   140.24     NA     NA
```

We're using the 'dcast' function, because we're wanting to output a data frame.  Then, we are specifying your melted data as the input.  The next part explains how to relate the data, with the left-hand side of the '~' equation specifying the ID (FY_Qtr) and the right-hand side of the '~' specifying the column variable combinations to use.  The 'value.var' argument then specifies (as a string) the variable to be used as the value.

Comment: @user2661475 Glad you're happy!  Please click the checkmark next to the answer to indicate that the solution worked for you to close out the question.

Answer (score 2):

+1 to @Dinre; that's a good solution, and it's worth learning reshape2.  In case you want to see how this can be done in base R, it's not too difficult:

```
data <- read.table(text="FY_Qtr       region     Lic_type    revenue
                      '2009 Q1'         'AP'       NCV       126.67
                      '2010 Q1'         'NA'       NCV       395.80
                      '2011 Q1'         'LA'       NCV       469.10
                      '2012 Q1'         'EMEA'     MR        173.85
                      '2013 Q1'         'JAPAN'    MR        140.24", 
                   header=TRUE)


expected_data           <- matrix(NA, nrow=5, ncol=5)
rownames(expected_data) <- data$FY_Qtr
colnames(expected_data) <- with(data, paste(region, Lic_type, sep="."))
diag(expected_data)     <- data$revenue
expected_data
        AP.NCV NA.NCV LA.NCV EMEA.MR JAPAN.MR
2009 Q1 126.67     NA     NA      NA       NA
2010 Q1     NA  395.8     NA      NA       NA
2011 Q1     NA     NA  469.1      NA       NA
2012 Q1     NA     NA     NA  173.85       NA
2013 Q1     NA     NA     NA      NA   140.24
```